# Xamarin Forms page are missing in Visual Studio 2019 to add

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have installed Xamarin in visual studio but i am not getting xamarin.Form. My old project is running but when i try to add new page i am not finding xamarin.forms page there to add. I have uninstalled and installed two times but this option is not coming . [image: When i try to Add page i am getting this there xamarin.Forms are missing.]

[image: My visual studio version description]

Can you help me to find out this issue.

Below component is installed 
[image: Installed Project]

Comment: That's odd. The only thing that I can think of is to repair the VS. You can also report it as an issue in VS portal.

Comment: i have uninstalled and installed two times

Comment: When you open the Visual Studio Installer and try to customise the VS, can you show us what components have been installed?

Comment: visual studio installer displaying xamarin is selected

Comment: Open **Visual Studio Installer**  -> **modify** .Make sure that the `.NET desktop development  ` and `Mobile development with .NET ` had been installed .

Comment: make sure you select the shared app and not the android/iOS app projects

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Please take a look i have added image that i have installed

Comment: @magicandre1981 project already created i want to change in project . Earlier project is created in vs2017.

Comment: yes, make sure this shared project is selected and here click on add->new item

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes i am doing same

Comment: You could post your issue to  Help -> Send Feedback -> report a problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really surprise they forget to add this. Micorsoft has fixed this issue let's wait for next release. [Microsoft developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1076493/xamarin-forms-page-are-missing-in-visual-studio-20.html)